# $.getScript() : error after fetching scripts

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

Previously , this piece of code was working fine (just a snippet .. there are more nested getScripts ).

```
 $.getScript('FileSaver.js',function(){
                    $.getScript( 'jszip.js',function(){ //do something})
                  });
```

after reusing it in my application , I keep getting this error in the callback:

> Expected  ' ; '

any idea why this is happening. I've tried many different js files and it always gives the same error.

Some more details:

Browser : IE11 , mode: 10

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you check in the console if the error is coming after the script is been loaded or before it?

Comment: Oh shoot.. it was happening because I didn't give it the proper url.
thanks for the hint!